# T-SQL Stored procedure, declaring variables within the exec

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure using T-SQL to insert variables into a table.  Using the method that I know of, you declare the variables in the creation of the stored procedure, but I believe it's possible to declare the variables as part of the exec statement to make the insert dynamic.  I've googled and googled and googled and cannot find anything that supports this.

Here is my example code as it stands with static variables:

```
create procedure spInsert as
    declare @insertValueOne varchar(5) = 'Test1'
    declare @insertValueTwo varchar(5) = 'Test2'
    declare @insertValueThree varchar(5) = 'Test3'
    declare @insertValueFour varchar(5) = 'Test4'

begin

insert into testTable
(ValueOne, ValueTwo, ValueThree, ValueFour)
values
(@insertValueOne, @insertValueTwo, @insertValueThree, @insertValueFour)

end

exec spInsert
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a situation where I can can use an execution script like this for example:

```
exec spInsert('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4')
```

Instead of creating static variables within the procedure. Allowing the user to execute the stored procedure without amending the contents of it.

Does this make sense?
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the parentheses.

Comment: the parentheses after exec spInsert? would it just insert my variables in the sequential order that they were declared in? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aguments with default value instead of local variables:

```
create procedure dbo.spInsert
   @insertValueOne   varchar(5) = 'Test1'
  ,@insertValueTwo   varchar(5) = 'Test2'
  ,@insertValueThree varchar(5) = 'Test3'
  ,@insertValueFour  varchar(5) = 'Test4'
AS
BEGIN
  -- You can still use local variables
  -- DECLARE @my_local_variable = UPPER(@insertValueOne); 

  INSERT INTO testTable(ValueOne, ValueTwo, ValueThree, ValueFour)
  VALUES (@insertValueOne, @insertValueTwo, @insertValueThree, @insertValueFour)
END;
```

Call:

```
-- named parameters (good practice, self-documenting)
EXEC spInsert @insertValueOne = 'Test1', @insertValueTwo = 'BBB';
-- positional parameters(order is crucial)
EXEC spInsert 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423004)**</kbd>

Naming user defined stored procedure with `sp` is not best practice.

---

> I think this looks like my solution

No it isn't your stored procedure does not accept any arguments.

```
create procedure spInsert as
    declare @insertValueOne varchar(5) = 'Test1'
    declare @insertValueTwo varchar(5) = 'Test2'
    declare @insertValueThree varchar(5) = 'Test3'
    declare @insertValueFour varchar(5) = 'Test4'

begin

insert into testTable
(ValueOne, ValueTwo, ValueThree, ValueFour)
values
(@insertValueOne, @insertValueTwo, @insertValueThree, @insertValueFour)

end
```

Comment: I think this looks like my solution, however, I would like some variables static and some as dynamic arguments - is this possible? would the default values remain as 'Test1' etc until I overwrite them? thanks for the comment re: best practice, I'll rename them to something else. Also, when you say positional parameters is this just over writing the preset variables in the order that they were created?

Comment: @roastbeeef Play with LiveDemo. Of course you can add local variables to your stored procedure. With positional parameters order is very important.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there.  Your code contains a few errors.  My example only demonstrates a fraction of what can be achieved with stored procedures.  See Microsoft's MSDN [help docs on procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx) for more.

The example uses a temp procedure (the hash in front of the name makes it temp).  But the principles apply to regular SPs.

**SP**

```
/* Declares a temp SP for testing.
 * The SP has two parameters, each with a default value.
 */
CREATE PROCEDURE #TempExample
    (
        @ValueOne    VARCHAR(50) = 'Default Value One',
        @ValueTwo    VARCHAR(50) = 'Default Value Two'
    )
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        @ValueOne    AS ReturnedValueOne,
        @ValueTwo    AS ReturnedValueTwo    
END
GO
```

I've included the *SET NOCOUNT ON* statement.  MSDN recommends this in the section on best practice.

> Use the SET NOCOUNT ON statement as the first statement in the body of
>   the procedure. That is, place it just after the AS keyword. This turns
>   off messages that SQL Server sends back to the client after any
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, and DELETE statements are executed.
>   Overall performance of the database and application is improved by
>   eliminating this unnecessary network overhead.

In the example I've given each parameter a default value, but this is optional.  Below shows how you can call this SP using variables and hard coded values.

**Example Call**

```
/* We can declare varaiabels outside the SP
 * to pass in values.
 */
DECLARE @ParamOne    VARCHAR(50) = 'Passed Value One';

/* Calling the SP with params.
 * You can use variables or hard  coded values.
 */
EXECUTE #TempExample @ParamOne, 'Passed Value Two';
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps..
remove parentheses

```
exec spInsert 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'
```